# Сравнение двух массивов c помощью numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Необходимо сравнить два массива: если элементы на четных индексах первого массива больше второго, то тогда `true`, для нечетных индексов тоже самое. В итоге должен быть получен новый "бурливый" массив `true/false`.

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([5,0,1])
```

Как реализовать данное сравнение? С помощью `np.where`?

Comment: можете привести пример входных данных (по 6-10 элементов) и особенно выходных данных?

Comment: В текущей формулировке непонятно что вы хотите получить на выходе и чем вам не подходит `a > b`?

Comment: нужно сравнить четные и нечетные элементы двух массивов. возможно пример непоказательный, но условно на выходе должен быть массив (true,false,true). у меня получилось отдельно сравнить четные и нечетные, но не могу это сделать сразу, чтобы был один массив, а не два. res1=b[::1]>a[::1]
res2=a[1::2]>b[1::2]

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста [в вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1036399/edit) небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: массив a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5] и b = np.array([5,3,4,0,2], задача: если четные элементы первого массива больше второго, то тогда true, для нечетных наоборот: должны быть больше элементы 2 массива.в итоге должен быть получен след результат: res[true,false,true,true,false ]. у меня получается только сравнивать отдельно четные и нечетные, но в один массив соединить не могу

Comment: [что делать с ответами на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проверяем четность индекса и в зависимости от результата выбираем одно из условий:

```
In [57]: res = np.where(
                   np.arange(1, len(a)+1) % 2 == 0, 
                   a > b, 
                   b > a
         )
```

Результат:

```
In [58]: res
Out[58]: array([ True, False,  True,  True, False])
```

Answer (score 1):

Допустимо ли создать массив индексов? Индексы начинаются с 1?

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
B = np.array([5, 3, 4, 0, 2])
I = np.argpartition(A, 0)
R = np.logical_or(np.logical_and(1 - (I + 1) % 2, A > B),
                  np.logical_and((I + 1) % 2, A < B))
print(type(R), R)
```

**Вывод:**

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> [ True False  True  True False]
```

Демо на [Rextester](https://rextester.com/VEUR45667).

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
res=a>b
res[::2]=a[::2]<b[::2]
```